# Using < operator in joinLeft Zend_Db_Table gives 'Invalid parameter number' error

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, left-join

I have been trying to select the latest messages sent/received for a specific user in Zend_Db_Table. I've got the query working fine in MySQL but when I try to do it with joinLeft it gives an error.
Code for the query in Zend_Db_Table:

```
$select=$this->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('m1'=>'messages'))
->joinLeft(array('m2'=>'messages'), 'm1.from_id=m2.from_id AND m1.date_created < m2.date_created')
->where('m2.date_created IS NULL')
->where('m1.from_id=? OR m1.to_id=?', $to)
->order('m1.date_created DESC');
```

The problem is in the additional condition in joinLeft(). If I replace '<' with '=', I get no error but that is not what serves the purpose.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put code  " ... AND m1.date_created < m2.date_created" in new line, like this

```
$select=$this->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('m1'=>'messages'))
->joinLeft(array('m2'=>'messages'), 'm1.from_id=m2.from_id')
->where('m1.date_created < m2.date_created')
->where('m2.date_created IS NULL')
->where('m1.from_id=? OR m1.to_id=?', $to)
->order('m1.date_created DESC');
```

Comment: @tasmaniski- Actually, that code needs to be in the joinLeft() ON condition. It wouldn't work if I put it in where clause.

Comment: I am doing like that and not getting an error... if you solved send the answer.

Comment: What is "that"? What are you doing? I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: Your query looks OK, plz try to echo $select; (or error_log($select)) and execute it in MySQL. You will see error that you must correct. If query in MySQL is right, see this bug, maybe you have that case: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1343

Comment: I'll check out the link in a moment by the way there is no problem with the query. It works fine in phpmyadmin. I did my homework before posting my problem here you see.